# How can I get the Wikidata inter-language links?

Tags: wikidata

I'm trying to get hold of the Wikidata inter-language links, i.e. a file listing all of the articles and which articles they are linked to in other languages.

( http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Glossary#Sitelink )

It seems like this should exist, and such a file seems available in the Wikidata data dumps: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/

I would have thought the one I want is "...langlinks.sql.gz", which is described as "Wiki interlanguage link records." That file is only 32 KB though, and the SQL file only produces a few thousand lines.

What am I not understanding? Is it possible to get a list of these links?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official [Wikidata dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/) are still in a very early stage.

At the moment, you might find [these processed files](http://semanticweb.org/RDF/Wikidata/) helpful, especially the one that ends with links.ttl.gz (currently http://semanticweb.org/RDF/Wikidata/turtle-20130801-links.ttl.gz), which is a [Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_%28syntax%29) file that provides the inter-language links extracted from the Wikidata dump.

The [export scripts](https://github.com/mkroetzsch/wda) are available on GitHub, and you might also find the corresponding [announcement on the mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/wikidata-l@lists.wikimedia.org/msg02553.html) interesting.

Please also have a look at the related question [How can I download the complete Wikidata database?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/107/70)

Answer (score 1):

To get the inter-language aka sitelinks *for a limited set of items* use [the API](http://wikidata.org/w/api.php), for instance item Q1 and Q2:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q1|Q2&props=sitelinks%2Furls

As [answered on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16647932/373710) you can also query by language and page title:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Ore%20Mountains&languages=cs|de|es|fr|it|pl|pt|ru&props=sitelinks%2Furls