# Torrent for Wikidata dump

Tags: data-request, wikidata, wikipedia, bittorrent

I'm looking for Wikipedia (`enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2`) and a Wikidata (`latest-all.json.bz2` ) dumps. The files are quite large (the latter has ~47GB) and my internet connection tends to stop while downloading.

I'm looking for torrent files. I found [one for Wikipedia](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents), but I cannot find one for Wikidata. Is there any?

Comment: "Try downloading from command line using `wget --continue url`. Creating a torrent is difficult because the file needs to be updated often." From https://t.me/joinchat/AZriqUj5UagVMHXYzfZFvA

Comment: these answers may be old (2013) but take a look https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/107/1511

Comment: I think it worth to create a torrent e.g. quarterly. For some, like me, an 3 months old dump would be almost as useful as the latest one as long as data structure haven't changed. If I can prove that my concept - for me finding the relationships (parent-child, teacher-pupil) between composers - works, I can download the latest version after that.

Answer (score 0):

They may have changed their site, but [the link](https://meta.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents) you shared now has magnet  links to torrents near the bottom.