# Download Wikipedia articles from a specific category

Tags: wikipedia

I know that I can download English Wikipedia Dump, but I was wondering if I can download only articles for a specific category-subject.

For instance, can I download articles related to Mathematics or Biology or Medicine only?

If this is not available, is there any way to find a list of all the articles related to one subject?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikipedia [Special Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport) feature does exactly this.

More details in [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/79/169).